# Authorize.NET with Kohana 3.0

Tags: kohana

I am trying to use Authorize.Net in a kohana 3.0 project. I have set up the module in the bootstrap.php file.
I want to best understand the process before I focus on the code. In their sample code, it is written.

```
<?php
require_once 'anet_php_sdk/AuthorizeNet.php'; // Include the SDK you downloaded in Step 2
$api_login_id = 'I_put_my_login_id_here';
$transaction_key = 'and_my_transaction_key_here;
$amount = "5.99";
$fp_timestamp = time();
$fp_sequence = "123" . time(); // Enter an invoice or other unique number.
$fingerprint = AuthorizeNetSIM_Form::getFingerprint($api_login_id,
  $transaction_key, $amount, $fp_sequence, $fp_timestamp)
?>

<form method='post' action="https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll">
<input type='hidden' name="x_login" value="<?php echo $api_login_id?>" />
<input type='hidden' name="x_fp_hash" value="<?php echo $fingerprint?>" />
<input type='hidden' name="x_amount" value="<?php echo $amount?>" />
<input type='hidden' name="x_fp_timestamp" value="<?php echo $fp_timestamp?>" />
<input type='hidden' name="x_fp_sequence" value="<?php echo $fp_sequence?>" />
<input type='hidden' name="x_version" value="3.1">
<input type='hidden' name="x_show_form" value="payment_form">
<input type='hidden' name="x_test_request" value="false" />
<input type='hidden' name="x_method" value="cc">
<input type='submit' value="Click here for the secure payment form">
</form>
```

So, I suppose a user accesses my website and tries to buy a product. I handle the process into the controller. I will use the php_curl.

```
public function action_authorize(){
$url = 'https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll';

                    $post_string = '';
                    $request = curl_init($url);

                    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // set to 0 to eliminate header info from response
                    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // Returns response data instead of TRUE(1)
                    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string); // use HTTP POST to send form data
                    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); // uncomment this line if you get no gateway response.

                    $post_response = curl_exec($request); // execute curl post and store results in $post_response

                    curl_close($request);

                    $response_array = explode($post_values["x_delim_char"],$post_response);
}
```

Here my problem is how can I know the server response to my query result in *$response_array*. How to identify error codes ?
Another thing, I enable the Authorize module. How can I access the *'api_login'* and the
    *'transaction_key'* from my controller ?
When I do this in the controller, I get an error
*

```
$authorize = new Authorize;
$authorize->api_login;
```

- gives an error.
  In fact I want to be able to implement Authorize.NET module in Kohana3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your Authorize.Net SDK classes in application/vendor/anet_php_sdk/

Demo Controller Method:

```
class Controller_Payment extends Controller_Template
{
    // Set properties at the top of the class for easier changes later
    $this->authorize_url = 'https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll';
    $this->api_login_id = 'I_put_my_login_id_here';

    public function action_authorize()
    {
        require Kohana::find_file('vendor', 'anet_php_sdk/AuthorizeNet');

        if($_POST)
        {
            $request = curl_init($this->authorize_url);

            // Build your post string
            $post_string = http_build_query($_POST);

            // The rest of the Authorize.net code
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
            curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            $post_response = curl_exec($request);
            curl_close($request);

            $response_array = explode($post_values["x_delim_char"],$post_response);

            // Look in your SDK docs to determine the actual values you need
            // to check to verify that the transaction was successful:
            if($response_array['code'] == 200)
            {
                Request::current()->redirect('success/page');
            }
            else
            {
                // Error handling
            }
        }

        $transaction_key = 'transaction_key_here;
        $amount = "5.99";
        $fp_timestamp = time();
        $fp_sequence = "123" . time(); // Enter an invoice or other unique number.
        $fingerprint = AuthorizeNetSIM_Form::getFingerprint($this->api_login_id,
            $transaction_key, $amount, $fp_sequence, $fp_timestamp)

        $this->template->content = View::factory('payment/page')
            ->set('api_login_id', $this->api_login_id)
            ->set('amount = $amount)
            ->set('fp_timestamp = $fp_timestamp)
            ->set('fp_sequence = $fp_sequence)
            ->set('fingerprint', $fingerprint);
    }
}
```

Since you asked, accessing the POST variables from the controller:

```
$transaction_key = $_POST['transaction_key'];
```

View file (views/payment/page.php):

```
<form method='post' action="payment/authorize">
<input type='hidden' name="x_login" value="<?php echo $api_login_id?>" />
<input type='hidden' name="x_fp_hash" value="<?php echo $fingerprint?>" />
<input type='hidden' name="x_amount" value="<?php echo $amount?>" />
<input type='hidden' name="x_fp_timestamp" value="<?php echo $fp_timestamp?>" />
<input type='hidden' name="x_fp_sequence" value="<?php echo $fp_sequence?>" />
<input type='hidden' name="x_version" value="3.1">
<input type='hidden' name="x_show_form" value="payment_form">
<input type='hidden' name="x_test_request" value="false" />
<input type='hidden' name="x_method" value="cc">
<input type='submit' value="Click here for the secure payment form">
</form>
```